# How to tell boss about pregnancy?

Tags: awkward-situations, rudeness, coworkers, ireland

I am about 22 weeks pregnant and it's getting to the point where it's hard to hide! I haven't told my boss or any coworkers yet.

I have a doctors note saying the due date etc.

I'm a bit of a wimp and my boss is a man so I hate these kinds of conversations.

Would it be rude if I just handed him the doctor's note or emailed him? What would you say?

Comment: How big is the team/company (how many of you)? how's your boss attitude on a day-by-day basis? rather nice/cool? pretty rough?

Comment: The company is small about 50 employees and there are 12 people on my floor but I only closely work with a few of them. I've had some arguments with my boss and there have been times where he's been moody but overall he's usually nice.

Comment: Do you have regular one-on-one meetings with your boss?

Answer (score 87):

Assuming you're planning on taking a maternity leave and then coming back to work, that is the only thing you need to tell your boss. Bosses like to plan workload and know if people are going to be away. It's not that you're sharing your personal good news with them.

So, send them an email asking for a 15 minute meeting. Before the meeting (Before asking for it if there's a good chance the boss will see you immediately):

- find out what (if any) protected maternity leave you are entitled to
- decide how long a leave you plan to take. Where I live, 4 months is the minimum and a lot of people take a year. But even if you plan to take 2 weeks, make your decision for now.
- find out about daycare options near your employer or home, and get on a waiting list if the length of your remaining pregnancy and planned leave total the same or less as the current waiting list length.
- if you do not intend to return to this job, there may be benefits (such as continued insurance coverage) to being on leave rather than resigning immediately. Understand all of that before communicating any decisions to your boss.

Then at the meeting you say:

> I need to let you know that I have great personal news! I'm expecting my first child and plan to take maternity leave probably at the end of September or early October. I am planning a leave of x weeks, so I expect to return roughly the nth week of y. I have daycare arrangements in place already.

A good boss will thank you and record the dates you said.

If you are asked things like "when is your due date?" you do not need to answer. You can say something like "I believe I will start the leave at the end of September. If it becomes necessary to stop working sooner I will let you know. At the moment everything is going great." If you are asked about reduced duties, or told "oh, guess I should cancel that training for you in August" give a BIG smile and assure your boss that everything is going great and there's no need to make any changes or adjustments. If you get any kind of anger, pushback, how-can-you-do-this-to-me or why-didn't-you-tell-me-sooner again a BIG smile and "this is great news for me, I'm happy to share it with you now." If you liked this boss I might have suggested "now that I'm past the dangerous part" or something more personal, but there's no need for it.

Some bosses may ask you if you're ready to announce to the whole group and help you to do so (such as mentioning your projected leave date at a planning meeting in the near future) -- if you feel shy about telling everyone, consider before the meeting whether you want this sort of help from your boss.

Keep two thoughts upmost in your head all the time:

- I am telling my boss about my planned leave so that my boss can do longterm planning for the business
- I don't care if my boss is happy that I am having a baby. I don't need approval from my boss, my news is good no matter what anyone else thinks of it.

Congratulations and enjoy the next 20 years. It's quite a ride!

Comment: "If you are asked things like "when is your due date?" you do not need to answer." I agree that there should be no obligation to answer, and if the pregnant woman does not want to, she should not. But is there a 'tactical' reason not to tell this information to your boss?

Comment: @Pakk some people ask questions to set up for something less pleasant. How long have you known? --> you could have told me earlier. When are you due? --> you can work longer / you can't work that long. Are you throwing up / tired / gaining weight? --> I will change your duties. None of these prying questions need to be answered. Our medical privacy is still a thing.

Comment: @KateGregory This has the added benefit of not giving them ammunition to unfairly dismiss you based on other grounds "unrelated" to the pregnancy.

Comment: Great answer. The only thing I might suggest adding is a discussion about announcing the news more widely (so the boss doesn't accidentally steal the OP's thunder or otherwise share before she's ready, and alternatively so he can help spread the word if she's shy of doing so herself).

Comment: With regards to telling them when your due date is, isn't that relevant to your maternity leave entitlements in some countries? In which case surely it would be relevant information, which the manager could expect to be given?

Comment: Some people work until they are in labour. Others stop as much as a month before they are due. "When will your leave start?" is a legitimate question. "Give me a piece of personal medical information" is not - even if the two are related and can be deduced from each other. It's important to answer the legit question (rewording when you answer, so not "my due date is" but "I expect my leave to start") to clearly communicate that "you don't get to demand personal details from me like that."

Comment: @KateGregory due date actually is far more important than "when does your leave start." If you say, I will leave on the 13th of June, it really does matter if the due date is the 14th or the 31st. Early and late births are very common. This allows a boss to plan for some extra wiggle room. I say this as both a boss and a parent.

Comment: @AaronHarun I am sure you don't mean to be patronizing, but this is exactly what the OP wants to avoid. The job of predicting the leave start from the due date belongs to the pregnant one, not to others. Yes, early births happen, as do late ones. So does bedrest and many other things. The decision to take a leave early or to keep working past the predicted leave date should not be made for the employee. If the boss is super concerned about the precise date then the boss can ask more questions, but at this point only a vague guess is possible. Made **by** the pregnant one, not **for** her.

Comment: Where did OP state she wants to avoid stating the due date? OP states she doesn't want to have a conversation with the person about it because "my boss is a man so I hate these kinds of conversations"  but was fine handing the doctor's note with the due date on it. AND since there are legal regulations around what work pregnant women can and can not do around the globe, working hours, time off, health insurance payments etc, depending on jurisdiction, due date actually is legally important information for a company and she is _required_ by irish law to provide it to get paternity benefits.

Answer (score 30):

As this is **Ireland** please familiarize yourself with Irish law on your entitlement to maternity leave.

This is a good link : [Citizen's Information on Maternity Leave](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/employment/employment_rights_and_conditions/leave_and_holidays/maternity_leave.html)

Note the conditions on giving notice :

**Do not delay doing this.**

> Notice: You must give your employer at least 4 weeks' written notice of your intention to take maternity leave and you must also provide your employer with a medical certificate confirming your pregnancy. If you intend to take the additional 16 weeks’ maternity leave you must provide your employer with at least 4 weeks' written notice. Both these notices can be given at the same time.

So just set up a simple meeting giving your boss a quick head-ups *and* send an email giving formal notice of what (maternity) leave you intend to take.

Note that your entitlement to maternity leave is (almost) absolute as long as you follow the rules, so your employer cannot argue with you.  He may or may not ask you to modify your intended arrangements, but as I understand it (IANAL) you don't need to accept his wishes, so you are in a position of strength here and should have no worries.

As an employer he should be perfectly reasonable (if surprised) at this and not give you any trouble.  I think a quick casual conversation (knock on his door and give that's quick heads-up with a rough plan) will deal with the initial news breaking.  Then just follow up in writing and/or email for formal legal reasons with solid dates.

And beyond that good luck.

Comment: Not that your answer is unhelpful, but I don't understand what the legal aspects of maternity leave have to do with IPS.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I give **practical** advice not artificially limited by narrow-minded interpretations of "IPS" Q&A.  If you don't understand why a legal deadline is important in this case I'd suggest you should refrain from advising people on real world problems.  This extremely narrow minded view of IPS that you and some others have would, if applied, lead to incomplete and practically useless answers that ignore real world issues that would make matters more difficult for people needing advice if those matters were ignored.

Comment: If the OP were interested in legal aspects of their situation, she would have asked on legal.SE or workplace.SE instead. Your answer would've been spot-on there.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev IPS answers which ignore the **real** world are utterly useless.  People making them are wasting everyone's time.

Comment: I'm not saying that giving practical advice is not OK. I'm saying that answers on this site must address the IPS part as well. In your answer, the IPS part is a single sentence suggesting to set up a meeting with no explanation of why it is necessary.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Because it makes a big difference to the nature of the interaction. In countries with good maternity legislation, the required and expected behaviour is very different from countries without. The law also frequently puts specific limits on what the employer can and can't ask and respond with. Proper interpersonal behaviour is culturally dependent.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Bluntly your last statement was a gross distortion of my answer.  This fantasy of the "Pure IPS answer" just doesn't address any aspect of context or the particular *practicalities* of situations.  And, in this particular case (and many others) the OP understanding their legal position is a key aspect of them have the confidence to do what they need to.  Let go of this nonsensensical idea of the Pure IPS answer - it doesn't really help anyone.

Comment: I have to say, I agree with @DmitryGrigoryev somewhat. This answer is about the legal and procedural aspects of maternity in the workplace. It doesn't focus on the best way to finesse the situation with the Boss. While good advice, If the OP wanted Legal or HR advice there are other sites for that. What is the polite way to inform said Boss and keep them "on-side" (no assumptions about illegal and inappropriate response?) I suspect the pregnancy is not as secret as the OP thinks and early disclosure is best, purely from an IPS perspective but, that is not what you say.

Comment: @Jodrell To produce such a "finessed" answer requires we either understand both parties' psychology to a high degree (which we don't) or we start listing every possible scenario (which is ludicrous).  My reading is that what the OP needs is *confidence* that what they're asking is not a problem, *should not* become one and that *if it does* that they're right.  But also that the delay in telling the boss could ultimately backfire.  This is what I mean by seeing beyond an "pure IPS" answer - see the context, see the underlying problem and *fix that*.

Answer (score 16):

> Would it be rude if I just handed him the doctor's note or emailed him?

As an employee, I've done similar things only to bosses (once, small company, 2 partners) who I couldn't deal with anymore (because of *their* really bad attitudes), and did it just before I quit (as all but one in a team of seven did too). We all did it on purpose, with no explanation, but we were fed up, and **yes, we wanted to be rude.** We handed our notice without a word, and didn't answer any questions.  We were out, period.

**So I'd definitely recommend not to do that.**  It would indeed be rude.

Now, as a business owner, **I'd appreciate if you would tell me as soon as possible**. Just be nice.  :)

> You: Hi boss, I have something to tell you.
>
> Me: Hi Alice. How can I help?
>
> You: I'm 22 weeks pregnant.
>
> Me: Congratulations!

From there, let's talk about you for a few minutes (be nice and "pleasantries" on both sides), then switch back to business, so that I can deal with the upcoming events and organize my schedules, team, check with you what you'll need, when and how you'll leave, and so on.

You don't have to be scared, unless your boss is really mean and a [ you name it ]. Be nice and professional, let him know, that's it. *But it should be a 1-on-1 meeting. Not by mail or just handing them a doctor's note*.

Comment: I have never dealt with pregnancy, but I'd point out Kate Gregory's comment on her post regarding not saying when you're due/how long you've been pregnant. *some people ask questions to set up for something less pleasant. How long have you known? --> you could have told me earlier. When are you due? --> you can work longer / you can't work that long. Are you throwing up / tired / gaining weight? --> I will change your duties* Curious what you think about that.

Comment: @AzorAhai : I'm definitely not this kind of person, so I wouldn't use any information against the pregnant lady. BUT I'm pretty sure many would do it like suggested by Kate. Unfortunately:/